# How to remove warning AD0001 in .Net Core project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, dependencies, analyzer

This is the warning message

> warning AD0001: Analyzer
> 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Analyzers.TopLevelParameterNameAnalyzer'
> threw an exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' with
> message 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'.

[image]

Any kind of help is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: This GitHub comment could help you: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/14723#issuecomment-588389938

Answer (score 3):

Check this https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/14723

Disable analyzer in Project file for testing purpose only.

```xml
<PropertyGroup> <DisableImplicitAspNetCoreAnalyzers>true</DisableImplicitAspNetCoreAnalyzers>
</PropertyGroup>
```

After disabling this, check if you can still build the project.Check if any install package have prior version dependency.

Answer (score 3):

I have been accessing

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.MVC

package to access HttpContextAccessor and that causes the WARNING.

I solved this by reinstalling dependency/reference for **HttpContextAccesstor** and it lands me to this package

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions

SOLVED

Answer (score 3):

As per:
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/41794

Adding this to a PropertyGroup in the .csproj file fixed this for me in minimal API .net 6.0.

```
    <NoWarn>AD0001</NoWarn>
```

The cause in my case is the way the route mapping is done.

```cs
// I use this because it's cleaner and the GetAllTodo function has DI parameters
app.MapGet("/manage/todos", GetAllTodo);

// but the following does not raise AD0001
app.MapGet("/manage/todos", () => GetAllTodo());
```